# Troubleshooting `InternalPreventSleep`

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake, power-management

My MBPr has been draining itself frequently overnight if not plugged in. I noticed today when I had the lid open, it would unlock itself with my Apple Watch - no input from me. I looked in Console and saw suspect `InternalPreventSleep` messages by searching for "Wake". This seems to be a log of when it happens. Are there any techniques to figure out what is causing this process to kick in?

Comment: is your wake for wifi access turned on ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yea but thats under power adapter mode, not battery mode. perhaps its 2 separate things i'm seeing?

Answer (score 1):

As for the Wake up

Check your Bluetooth settings for Wake

[image]

also for the WiFi wake
 [image]

both in your system preferences

then run the `pmset -g cap` in Terminal to see what is going on

followed by

You can inspect current settings using

```
pmset -g
```

Finally run `log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"` 
to see specifically who woke it up.
let it finish loading last 4 weeks

Then do a simple test..
under Apple logo Select

> Sleep

, and wait 30 seconds to see if it wakes up.